Does tkinter mainloop not run lines after it
I am trying to make a function that makes a window for the user to press a button. When the user presses the button, a value, True, is returned to the code that called this function.
The code that I have currently is:
def function(self, root):
    def done():
        window.destroy()

    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry('500x100')
    window.title('Test')

    button = tk.Button(window, text='Press Me', command=done)
    button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)

    window.mainloop()

    return True

However, when I run it, even though the window is destroyed, the value is not returned. Any help is appreciated, thanks. Apologies if this question was unclear, I will rectify immediately.

Use root.wait_window(window) instead of window.mainloop().  Note that it is better to run .mainloop() only once.

Another solution is to add root.quit() to the first code example inside done. .quit() is there to stop the last started .mainloop().

Don't put the solution in the question. Click on "Your Answer" below to add it as an answer. I've rolled back your last edit.

To get the value returned by a function, you need to assign it: value = function(args). There is not enough code to understand what you are trying to achieve. Tkinter has dialogs and messageboxes. You can set a flag instead of a return value. The solution depends on the context of your application.

Because the "self" parameter is not used in the code sample I'll omit it from this comment. Try root = tk.Tk() print(function(root)), I was given "True" in the console.
